# Strip leading, trailing and more than 1 space from String

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift, nsregularexpression

I have string:

```
Simple text   with    spaces
```

I need regular expression which select:

- leading
- trailing
- more than 1 space

Example:

```
_ - space

_Simple text __with ___spaces_
```

Comment: please explain question properly.

Answer (score 5):

My 2ct:

```
let text = "    Simple text   with    spaces    "
let pattern = "^\\s+|\\s+$|\\s+(?=\\s)"
let trimmed = text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(pattern, withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
println(">\(trimmed)<") // >Simple text with spaces<
```

`^\s+` and `\s+$` match one or more white space characters at the start/end of the string.

The tricky part is the `\s+(?=\s)` pattern, which matches one or more
white space characters  followed by another white space character which itself is *not* considered
part of the match (a "look-ahead assertion").

Generally, `\s` matches all white-space characters such as the space character itself, horizontal tabulation, newline, carriage-return, linefeed or formfeed. If
you want to remove only the (repeated) space characters then replace the pattern by

```
let pattern = "^ +| +$| +(?= )"
```

Comment: Be interesting to know if this outperforms the two-step for various possible strings, given the more complex regex is probably slower.

Comment: Just a note: the regex `\s` matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed. If you only want to match spaces us an actual space

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: No significant difference. For 1MB text: Your method: 0.572 seconds, my method 0.502 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the regular expression simple by doing the leading/trailing part as a second stage:

```
 let singlySpaced = " Simple text   with    spaces   "
      .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\s+", withString: " ", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
      .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

(assuming you want to strip all kinds of whitespace – you can adjust it down to just do only spaces fairly easily)

There are more complex regexprs that will do it in one shot, but personally I prefer the two-step version over obfuscation (and as @MartinR mentions, performance is very similar between the two, given a trim is a very lightweight operation vs a slower more-complex regex - so it’s really down to which you prefer the look of).

Comment: Maybe exist way to use only stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method. Example:  let singlySpaced = " Simple text   with    spaces   ".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("REGULAR EXPRESSION", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch). REGULAR EXPRESSION will select leading, trailing and more than 1 space? P.S. I need save perform time.

Comment: It’s easy to match leading/trailing/more than one thing at once (as Robert’s answer shows) with `^ |  +| $`.  The tricky part is what to replace it with if you want to strip – you want to replace leading/trailing with nothing, but replace multiple internal spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to clean your strings up:

```
var string : NSString = "  hello    world.  "
while string.rangeOfString("  ").location != NSNotFound { //note the use of two spaces
    string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("  ", withString: " ")
}
println(string)
string = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
println(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some good answers have been provided, but if you want a regex the following should work:

`^ |(?<= ) +| $`

The `|` indicates alternatives, the `^` is the beginning of a string, the `$` indicates the end of the string. So this matches beginning of the string followed by a space OR one or more spaces preceded by a space OR a space at the end of the string.

Comment: Thx, bit ` +` expression, select all spaces between words. I need start selecting from second whitespace in occurrence to end whitespace group. Example `word __word`.

Comment: You need a Look-behind assertion for that. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following will remove all the spaces

```
NSString *spaces =@"hi how are you "; 

NSString *withoutSpace= [spaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " 
                               withString:@" "];
withoutSpace = [withoutSpace stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This will work for removing all spaces but I believe he wants to leave some spaces behind. It appears that he wants to leave 1 space between words.

Comment: sorry please check updated answer ...he wants to remove ,trailing , leading and more than one , this will do the same

Comment: Yep, that'll do it! The other thing is that the language listed in the question is Swift, your code is Objective-C. Not that hard to convert but it's still a mismatch.

Comment: Perhaps not, I didn't downvote it so that's up to whoever did.

Answer (score -1):

**this function will leave one space between words**

```
let accountNameStr = "   test    test   "
    let trimmed = accountNameStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
    let textWithoutSpace = trimmed.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Output : **test test**